# Round timestamp to quarter of hour

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table and one of the columns is a timestamp. What I would like to do is a SQL query (BigQuery compatible) that rounds the timestamp of each line to the quarter of the hour previous to that time. 
Examples:

`2019-07-05 21:11:28 UTC -> 2019-07-05 21:00:00 UTC
2019-07-05 21:17:05 UTC -> 2019-07-05 21:15:00 UTC
2019-07-05 20:29:56 UTC -> 2019-07-05 20:15:00 UTC
2019-07-05 21:55:39 UTC -> 2019-07-05 21:45:00 UTC`

I found TIMESTAMP_TRUNC that can round to minutes, but this will round to the timestamp's minute, not the quarter.

Do you guys have any idea of how could I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ts, 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(UNIX_SECONDS(ts) - MOD(UNIX_SECONDS(ts), 15 * 60)) ts_rounded_to_quarter_of_hour
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Another, slightly refactored version is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ts, 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(ts_seconds_since_epoch - MOD(ts_seconds_since_epoch, 15 * 60)) ts_rounded_to_quarter_of_hour
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST([UNIX_SECONDS(ts)]) ts_seconds_since_epoch
```

And finally, my favorite version would be

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION TIMESTAMP_TRUNC_TO_QUATER_OF_HOUR(ts TIMESTAMP) AS ((
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(ts_seconds_since_epoch - MOD(ts_seconds_since_epoch, 15 * 60))
  FROM UNNEST([UNIX_SECONDS(ts)]) ts_seconds_since_epoch
));
SELECT ts, 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC_TO_QUATER_OF_HOUR(ts) AS ts_rounded_to_quarter_of_hour
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION TIMESTAMP_TRUNC_TO_QUATER_OF_HOUR(ts TIMESTAMP) AS ((
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(ts_seconds_since_epoch - MOD(ts_seconds_since_epoch, 15 * 60))
  FROM UNNEST([UNIX_SECONDS(ts)]) ts_seconds_since_epoch
));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-07-05 21:11:28 UTC' ts UNION ALL    --> 2019-07-05 21:00:00 UTC
  SELECT '2019-07-05 21:17:05 UTC' UNION ALL                 --> 2019-07-05 21:15:00 UTC
  SELECT '2019-07-05 20:29:56 UTC' UNION ALL                 --> 2019-07-05 20:15:00 UTC
  SELECT '2019-07-05 21:55:39 UTC'                           --> 2019-07-05 21:45:00 UTC
)
SELECT ts, 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC_TO_QUATER_OF_HOUR(ts) AS ts_rounded_to_quarter_of_hour
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Obviously, all three above versions return below [same] result

```
Row     ts                      ts_rounded_to_quarter_of_hour    
1       2019-07-05 21:11:28     UTC 2019-07-05 21:00:00 UTC  
2       2019-07-05 21:17:05     UTC 2019-07-05 21:15:00 UTC  
3       2019-07-05 20:29:56     UTC 2019-07-05 20:15:00 UTC  
4       2019-07-05 21:55:39     UTC 2019-07-05 21:45:00 UTC
```

Comment: Damn, amazing answer, thanks! I'll try all that on monday when I get to work and I'll let you know

Comment: How would I approach that if I needed to do the same when all I have is an hour (without preceding date)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using stored procedures you can do something like this:

```
declare @d datetime='2019-07-05 21:11:28'
select DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @d)/15*15, 0)
```

This works because the 0 integer in the example above is actually the start of the epoch (1900-01-01).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a beginner in SQL, so I've got a few questions: Why that date? Would I replace that specific date with my timestamp? That datetime, is that a timestamp? Or would I need to change the type of the variable? And what is that mi? What would be the query to change the table using that?

Comment: Mike, [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). Tomas, honestly, why that date? Because it's your first example.

Comment: Glad to help @TomasCardoso . I kept my example simple by just displaying the code for the first of your dates. The code will also work for your other three dates. `mi` is what `dateadd` and `datediff` uses to specify it is adjusting the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `timestamp_trunc()` and some date arithmetic:

```
select timestamp_add(timestamp_trunc(current_timestamp, hour),
                     interval cast(extract(minute from current_timestamp) / 15 as int64)*15  minute
                    )
```